# Trying to print out a total number of numbers ending with 7 in a randomly generated array

Tags: c++, recursion

```
// minicount.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

double evenOut(int arr[], int size, double count) {
    double evenCount = count;
    
    if (size == 0) {
        return evenCount;
    }

    if ((arr[size-1] % 2) == 0 ) {
        evenCount += 1;
        evenOut(arr, size - 1, evenCount);
    }
    else {
        evenOut(arr, size - 1, evenCount);
    }
}

double sevenFact(int arr[], int size, double count) {
    double sevenCount = count;
    string a = to_string(arr[size - 1]);

    if (size == 0) {
        //cout << "Final total number of 7's -> " << sevenCount << endl;
        //cout << "7 to the power of " << sevenCount << " is " << fixed << pow(7, sevenCount) << endl;
        return sevenCount;
    }
    
    if (a[a.length() - 1] == '7') {
        sevenCount += 1;
        sevenFact(arr, size - 1, sevenCount);
    }
    else {
        sevenFact(arr, size - 1, sevenCount);
    }

}


int main()
{
    const string FILE = "randArray.txt";
    const int SIZE = 1000;
    int arr[SIZE];  

    ofstream OUTPUTFILE(FILE);

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        arr[i] = (rand() % 100) + 1;
    }

    if (OUTPUTFILE.is_open()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            OUTPUTFILE << arr[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "ERROR: Could not open file." << endl;
    }

    cout << "EvenOut: The number of even numbers in " << FILE << " is: " << evenOut(arr, SIZE, 0) << endl;
   
    double x = sevenFact(arr, SIZE, 0);

    cout << "SevenFact: Total number of numbers ending with 7: " << x;

}
```

This is my current setup of code. I am trying to print out the total number of numbers ending with 7 in this array, but whatever number is being returned to x in the function call of SevenFact, isn't being stored properly. If I un-comment the two cout lines in the sevenFact function itself, the cout is printing the correct value in total, but whatever is returned is not that.

I setup the evenCount function the same way, and that is returning normally.

But something is wrong with sevenCount, and I cannot figure out what.

Comment: You are missing `return` statements in both evenOut and sevenFact, when making recursive calls you need to return the value returned by that call

Comment: BTW, recursive approach to this problem makes sense only for languages/compilers with tail call optimization, and AFAIK none of CPP compilers support that. Use iteration instead

Comment: One more - why don't you use modulo 7 in sevenFact, similarly as you do modulo 2 in evenOut?

Answer (score 2):

This comment is more for your teacher then for you ;)

Looks like you have a teacher (or C++ source) that is still teaching you "C". In C++ code would look more like this :

Tell your teacher to read the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) and update his material accordingly. Can you show this to him/her? I would be happy to talk about it too.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// learn to make functions for small logical steps
// this will make your final code very readable
// describing what is going on. Tip: when you want to 
// write comments in your code it is usually a sign to 
// make a function
auto create_random_values(std::size_t size)
{
    // use C++ random generator
    // to create evenly distributed values between 1-100 (inclusive)
    // I use statics here so the random generation is created
    // on first call, and reused for all later calls. (random generators have state, you should not recreate them all the time)
    static std::random_device entropy_source;
    static std::mt19937 random_generator{entropy_source()};
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_distribution{1,100};

    // Use std::vector in C++ whenever you have an array
    // and only knows its lenght at runtime. 
    std::vector<int> values(size);

    // it is good practice in C++ to use range based (not index based) for loops
    // whenever you can. 
    for(auto& value : values)
    {
        value = uniform_distribution(random_generator);
    }

    // or to describe intent even better, use no loops at all.
    // the last argument is a lambda expression
    // std::generate(values.begin(),values.end(), [&]{ return uniform_distribution(random_generator); });

    return values;
}

bool ends_with_7(const int value)
{ 
    // do NOT use std::pow it is a floating point function and will lead to rounding errors
    return (value % 10) == 7;
}

// pass vector by const reference
// - avoids copies
// - avoids function accidentally changing the content
auto count_numbers_ending_in_seven(const std::vector<int>& values)
{
    // this why C++ algorithm header is so useful
    // it contains all kind of useful reusable functions
    // that work nicely with containers like std::vector
    return std::count_if(values.begin(),values.end(), ends_with_7);
}

int main()
{
    auto values = create_random_values(100);

    for(const auto& value : values)
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
        if (ends_with_7(value)) std::cout << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "\nThe number of numbers ending in 7 = " << count_numbers_ending_in_seven(values);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. For a student, your explanations add a lot of value to the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `return` statements in both `evenOut` and `sevenFact`, when making recursive calls you need to return the value returned by that call

–
Lesiak